# Creating unique page for each person

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am trying to create an association between wine and wine maker.

I have a wine list page with a table that has wine's name, vintage, region, country, and maker.

I want user to be able to click the maker, then the user can see the wine maker's profile page. I don't know how to link to some wine maker profile page based on the name.

Wine maker will have many wines, but I don't know how to create a path for each wine maker's profile.

config/routes

```
Wine::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
root 'static_pages#index'
resources :wine_lists
resources :wine_makers
```

model/wine_list.rb

```
class WineList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :wine_maker_id
  belongs_to :wine_maker
end
```

model/wine_maker.rb

```
class WineMaker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wine_lists
end
```

wine_lists_controller.rb

```
class WineListsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html, :json

def new
    @wine_list = WineList.new
    @wine_maker = WineMaker.find(params[:wine_maker])
end

def index
    # @wine_maker = WineMaker.find_by_name(params[:wine_maker_id])
    @wine_list = WineList.all 
end

def create
    @wine_list = WineList.create(wine_list_params)
    redirect_to wine_list_path(@wine_list)
end

def show 
    @wine_list = WineList.find(params[:id])
    @wine_maker = WineMaker.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @wine_list = WineList.find(params[:id])
  @wine_list.update_attributes(params[:wine_list_params])
  respond_with @wine_list
end

def destroy
    @wine_list = WineList.find(params[:id])
    @wine_list.destroy

    redirect_to wine_lists_path, :notice => "Deleted"
end

private

def wine_list_params 
    params.require(:wine_list).permit(:name, :vintage, :region, :country, :vino_maker)
end
end
```

wine_makers_controller.rb

```
class WineMakersController < ApplicationController

def new
    @wine_maker = WineMaker.new
end

def index 
    @wine_maker = WineMaker.all
end

def create
    @wine_maker = WineMaker.create(wine_maker_params)
    redirect_to root_path
end


def show
    @wine_maker = WineMaker.find(params[:id])
end

private

def wine_maker_params
params.require(:wine_maker).permit(:name, :born_on, :nationality, :profile, :wine )
end
end
```

views/wine_lists/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Wine List</h1>

<table id="wine_lists" class="display">     
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th> 
      <th>Vintage</th> 
      <th>Region</th> 
      <th>Country</th> 
      <th>Maker</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  <% @wine_list.each do |wine| %>   
    <tr>
      <td><%= best_in_place wine, :name %></td>
      <td><%= best_in_place wine, :vintage %></td>
      <td><%= best_in_place wine, :region %></td>
      <td><%= best_in_place wine, :country, collection:  [ "Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Belarus", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Canada", "Chile", "China", "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "France", "Georgia", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Italy", "Japan", "Macedonia", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Morocco", "New Zealand", "Peru", "Portugal", "Romania", "Russia", "Serbia", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Switzerland", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan" ]  %></td>
      <td><%= link_to ":vino_maker", :controller => :wine_make_controller, :action => :index %></td>
      <td><button id="btnDeleteRow"><%= link_to 'Delete', wine, :method => "Delete" %></button></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is my solution worked?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing great so far! Keep it up.

Simply use the `#link_to` helper to get the job done:

```
link_to "Wine Maker", @wine_list.wine_maker
```

You'll notice that I didn't simply write `link_to "Wine Maker", @wine_maker`, because best practices in Ruby on Rails state that our controllers should only implement a single entity whenever it's possible.

Now, that `#link_to` will just link to the `#show` action of your `WineMakersController`. It's in your `/wine_makers/show.html.erb` that you'll be able to put profile page information.

**UPDATE**

Your `link_to` method should look like this in your view:

```
<td><%= link_to "Wine Maker", @wine_list.wine_maker, controller: "wine_makers", action: "show" %></td>
```

Or, if you wanted to keep your `@wine_maker` instance around in your `WineListsController`, you could do this for your `#link_to`:

```
<td><%= link_to "@wine_maker.name", @wine_maker %></td>
```

Comment: Hi Collin, thanks for your help! When I put link_to "Wine Maker", @wine_list.wine_maker, I get undefined method for "wine_maker". But when I put in just wine_maker only, it works, but it doesn't link to anywhere. (Dead link).

Comment: Started GET "/wine_lists" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-07-06 23:01:32 +0000
Processing by WineListsController#index as HTML
  WineList Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "wine_lists".* FROM "wine_lists"
  Rendered wine_lists/index.html.erb within layouts/application (61.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 267ms (Views: 265.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)                It seems like wine_maker is taking the user back to wine_list ._.

Comment: Do you have the proper relationship in your schema? If not, run the following migration: `rails g migration add_wine_maker_ref_to_wine_lists wine_maker:references`. That will add the proper `wine_maker_id` foreign key to `WineLists`. Sorry if there's any markdown issues...sending from my iPhone in rush hour.

Comment: Just did the migration but nothing has changed. Do I need to write new code in @wine_list controller to direct to wine_maker controller? no worry about the markdowns! I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: I am getting undefined method for wine_maker. undefined method `wine_maker' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_WineList:0xb5c752f8>
     I feel like I need to have perhaps @wine_maker = WineMaker.all in my controller for wine list?

Comment: I am a bout confused. But somehow this guy worked                                          <td><%= link_to "Profile", wine_maker_path(@wine_list) %></td>

Comment: You're getting an undefined method because you're trying to call `wine_maker` for an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Try grabbing the first object in that relation and calling the method again. It should work :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Collin! :) So.. here's my final code <code>(<%= link_to "Profile", wine_maker_path(@wine_list) %>)</code> This renders me the page with the address [link](http://localhost:3030/wine_makers/%23%3CActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_WineList:0xba08bc30%3E)[/link] It looks like it worked! Only problem is now that this is not taking to one unique wine maker page but wine maker page in general. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: That's because it's still waiting for a single `wine_maker` as an argument to the URL helper, like we talked about before. 

If you want to talk about this more, let's go ahead and do it in a chat session to avoid clogging up this thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82553/discussion-between-collin-graves-and-j-sanghoon).

Answer (score 0):

A small change to ***@Colin Graves*** answer as below should work for you unless the particular `wine_list` doesn't have a `wine_maker` associated with it.

```
<td><%= link_to "Wine Maker", wine.wine_maker, controller: "wine_makers", action: "show" %></td>
```

It should be `wine.wine_maker` instead of `@wine_list.wine_maker` because you are ***iterating*** `@wine_list` and also the `link_to` is within the ***loop***.

No wonder you got `undefined method error` when used `@wine_list.wine_maker` because `@wine_list` is a result of `WineList.all` which returns an **`ActiveRecord::Relation`**.